# Expected value and Variance

Tags: variance, expected-value

An investor pays a random amount of money into his bank account at the start of
each month for a total of 5 years. Let Xi denote the amount paid in at the start of
month i, and assume that is normally distributed with mean m and variance s2; here
m and s do not depend on the month. Assume also that these monthly investments
are independent of one another. The annual interest of 4% is compounded monthly.
Let Yi denote the present-value of the payment made at the beginning of month i,
and Y the present-value of the total investment.

(a) Calculate E (Yi) and Var(Yi) in terms of m and s.

Is it just as easy as E(Yi) = m and Var(Yi) = s^2

Or do you use the fact that

E[X] = Z ∞
−∞
xf(x) dx =: µ, and Var(X) = Z ∞
−∞
(x − µ)2f(x) dx.

I have been thinking about this question for last couple of days and cannot get my head around it
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hi: you wrote "paid in at the start of month i" so I take this to mean the cumulative sum of payments at the start of month $i$. So you need to find the distribution of the sum of payments. But it's still not too hard to do that if you use the fact that the sums of normals is normal and the means and the variances add.

Comment: The [tag:var] tag is for vector autoregressions. I have removed it.